# Why cannot I set an object inside NSMutable dictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsmutablearray

I have mutable dictionary object, which is part of Model class, declared as below.

```
@interface Obj : NSObject
@property  NSMutableDictionary *obj;
```

Values of obj are given below.

> {
>       0 =     (
>           0,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>       1 =     (
>           1,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>       2 =     (
>           2,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>       3 =     (
>           3,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>       4 =     (
>           4,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>       5 =     (
>           5,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>       6 =     (
>           6,
>           "5.00",
>           "5.59",
>           "14.00",
>           "14.59",
>           "22.00",
>           "22.59"
>       );
>   }

My app always crashes with following line of code when I try to set/update the values for a particular key.

```
[Obj.obj setValue:array3 forKey:string];
```

where array3 has following values.

> (
>       4,
>       5,
>       6,
>       14,
>       15,
>       22,
>       23
>   )

I have tried changing the line to

`[Obj.obj setObject:array3 forKey:string];`

But I always get the same error as below.

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSDictionaryI setObject:forKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6040001b3160'

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you're initializing the property with an immutable value (that's what the `__NSDictionaryI` is telling you). Perhaps something like:

```
obj = @{};
```

Or perhaps you're reading it out of a serializer. Those generally create immutable collections (though there are options for creating mutable collections depending on your serializer). Just defining the type of the pointer to the object doesn't make it that type; the object itself has to be created as a mutable dictionary.

At some point there should be a line of code like:

```
obj = [NSMutableDictionary new];
```

or

```
obj = [someImmutableDictionary mutableCopy];
```